# SBT: Slow resolution and failures when doing builds within Docker containers

Tags: scala, playframework, docker, sbt

I have a simple Play! application with nothing special going on in the `build.sbt`;

```
name := """project-name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  cache,
  ws,
  "com.googlecode.libphonenumber" % "libphonenumber" % "7.1.0"
)

// string metrics
libraryDependencies += "com.rockymadden.stringmetric" %% "stringmetric-core" % "0.27.4"

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

And inside a `Dockerfile` I'm attempting to build an executable of this application via the `activator dist`, `sbt dist` or `activator stage` commands.

All of the above work flawlessly when I run it on my computer. However, when I run exactly the same commands from within a docker container, I notice;

- SBT takes very long to resolve dependencies, it goes very slowly
  through the list of dependencies.
- The build fails with the following:
  `sbt.ResolveException: download failed:
  org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2!scalaz-core_2.10.jar(bundle)`

I'm doubting if this is an error that has to do with SBT or something specific to Docker containers.
Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Which sbt version are you using? Which activator version?

Comment: Also, does it works outside of docker?

Comment: @marcospereira thanks for taking the time to reply to this, but here is what `sbt about` outputs from within the docker container: `Detected sbt version 0.13.8
Cannot find sbt launcher 0.13.8
Please download:
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /root/.sbt/.lib/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar`
And yes, it does work outside of docker flawlessly.

Comment: @Ashesh Have you found solution?

Comment: @mixel no I haven't.

Comment: Outside of Docker, where it runs flawlessly, do you have anything special in `~/.sbt/0.13/` or `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/`?  I've put resolvers in there before, which causes a problem when the project is built elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know if these could be behind this? https://gist.github.com/asheshambasta/b669f6901c26e8a5aa18c7f8e5d18cf8

Comment: @PeterBecich Any updates on this? This is still a major pain point for us since we're unable to really use automated building because of this.

Answer (score 4):

[Mounting the `.ivy2` and `.sbt` directories in the container](https://github.com/tozny/docker-sbt-extras#using-sbt) increased the compiling speed significantly:

```
-v ~/.sbt:/root/.sbt -v ~/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer – but that isn't a viable option since this will not work for automated builds.